# Date Picker in jetpack compose bad resizing

Tags: datepicker, android-jetpack-compose, material3

If I use the new DatePicker api from jetpack compose and I set it a padding it will be showing overlaps like in this image
[image]

Comment: Same here! did you found any solution for this?

Comment: Nothing yet. You can vote to get more attention.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! anyway, maybe it's a SO device related problem. I've opened an issue in Google's tracker comparing the behaviour with Samsung S21 and Pixel 7 -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/286801436